# Select rows in SQL (server 2012) with Regex values that match input string

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2012

Instead of selecting rows based on whether their column values match a given regex, I want to select rows where their column values contain the regular expresion that match the input string.

I know this can be done in Postgres, however I am restricted to MS SQL Server 2012.

```
RULES TABLE

Rule_Name               Regex
Rule XXX                'Acc nr \d*$'
```

So If I run the below (example- not working)select statement I would expect Rule XXX to be in the result set

```
SELECT * FROM RULES
WHERE 'Acc nr 50059890019' LIKE Regex
```

Comment: SQL Server does not support, AFAIK, regex in its `LIKE` expressions, except for some rudimentary things like character classes.  You would have to use something like CLR to add the kind of regex support your want.

Comment: you mean,you pass parameter like "Rule XXX" then this "'Acc nr \d*$'" should be in where condition.IT is not very clear.